# Show And Hide the UIView With Same Animation In Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, show-hide, uiviewanimation

I have a `UITextField` **searchbox**, at first it's hidden, i want to show it with animation and it works. But when i hide it again, the animation happens suddenly, not with defined time in animation.

Here is my code :

```
    [UIView transitionWithView:searchbox duration:0.3 
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
    animations:^{searchbox.hidden = NO;}completion:NULL];

    [UIView transitionWithView:searchbox duration:0.3 
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
    animations:^{searchbox.hidden = YES;}completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Just increase its time when hiding to see the effect. Works fine at my side even at your given time but it is faster.

Comment: it's not about time, .hidden method can't do correct at this case with short animation time but .alpha can do it. @AadilAli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must use `.alpha` to hide or show `UIView`.

Correct code is :

```
[UIView transitionWithView:searchbox duration:0.3 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
animations:^{searchbox.alpha=1;}completion:NULL];

[UIView transitionWithView:searchbox duration:0.3 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
animations:^{searchbox.alpha=0;}completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use alpha property of view instead of hidden

```
[UIView transitionWithView:searchbox duration:0.3 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
animations:^{searchbox.alpha = 1.0;}completion:NULL];

[UIView transitionWithView:searchbox duration:0.3 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
animations:^{searchbox.alpha = 0;}completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 2):

To show

```
searchbox.alpha = 0;
searchbox.isHidden = NO;
[UIView transitionWithView:searchbox
             duration:0.3 
             options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
        animations:^{
          searchbox.alpha = 1.0
    }completion:NULL];
```

To hide

```
searchbox.alpha = 1.0;
searchbox.isHidden = NO;
[UIView transitionWithView:searchbox
             duration:0.3 
             options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
        animations:^{
          searchbox.alpha = 0
    }completion:^(isComplete){
      if (isComplete) {
         searchbox.isHidden = YES
      }}];
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a delay between calls of your animations.
Here is an example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(show) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) show {
    [UIView transitionWithView:searchbox duration:0.3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{searchbox.hidden = NO;}completion:NULL];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(hide) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) hide {
    [UIView transitionWithView:searchbox duration:0.3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{searchbox.hidden = YES;}completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Never do animation in viewDidLoad. Never try to guess when something should happen.